# Swift - Joining two tuple arrays based on their values

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples, swift4

I've a scenario where I have two arrays of tuples.

```
tuple1 = [(score1, index1), (score2, index2), (score3, index3)]
tuple2 = [(date1, index1), (date2, index2), (date3, index4)]
```

I want to get the scores and dates from these tuples and create a new array of tuples such that it contains the score and date having the same index like this:

```
tuple3 = [(score1, date1), (score2, date2)]
```

How can I implement this? What is the best practice to follow in this scenario? 
**Note:** The arrays can be of different sizes

**My implementation for the scenario is as follows:**

```
var tuple3 = [(Double, Date)]()
    for (i,psa) in tuple1.enumerated() {

        let date = tuple2.filter({ $0.1 == i })

        if date.count == 1 {
            let newTuple = (tuple1.0, date[0].0)
            tuple3.append(newTuple)
        }
    }
```

Is this a right way to do it or is there a better one?

Comment: What you mentioned as `tuple3` is array of dictionary or a nested array? You should use an array of dictionary instead of nested array here.

Comment: Something like `[["date": "12-Sep-2018", "score": 45], ["date": "14-Sep-2018", "score": 48], ["date": "16-Sep-2018", "score": 79]]`.

Comment: Could you clarify because of two possible interpretations (see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52494576/swift-joining-two-tuple-arrays-based-on-their-values/52494721#comment91930586_52494721)

Comment: The index is something we add from the cell from which the data is populated (indexPath.row of the cell). There can be scenarios where the textfields in the cell can have only one value and I need to remove them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let tuple1 = [("score1", "index1"), ("score2", "index2"), ("score3", "index3")]
let tuple2 = [("date1", "index1"), ("date2", "index2"), ("date3", "index4")]

let t2Dict = tuple2.reduce(into: [String:String]()) { (dict, args) in
    let (date, index) = args
    dict[index] = date
}

let tuple3 = tuple1.compactMap { args -> (String, String)? in
    let (score, index) = args
    guard let date = t2Dict[index] else { return nil }
    return (score, date)
}
```

It's not as pretty as the others, but it's far more efficient to collapse one of the tuples into a dictionary first.

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
let v1 = [("1","2"),("3","4")]

let v2 = [("1A","2A"),("3A","4A")]

let res = zip(v1,v2).map { ($0.0 , $1.0) } // [("1", "1A"), ("3", "3A")]

print(res)
```

Comment: I tested your code and it gives `[("score1", "date1"), ("score2", "date2"), ("score3", "date3")]` (I converted the values as String), you have then an extra `(score3, date3)` but the values doesn't concord because they have different indexes.

Comment: @Larme the op means etc.... not only the first 2 items ( i think it's what meant  ) ,  else it's a simple getting the first 2 items of an array

Comment: The issue of describing the result as "the score and date having the same index ", is that "index" car be interpreted as an array index, and also because one of the value of the tuple in named indexN. Author should clarify. We understood it each one as the other way.

Comment: @Larme anyway the op should give feedback

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
let tuple3 = tuple1.compactMap({  (scoreInTuple1, indexInTuple1) -> (String, String)? in
    if let tupleIn2 = tuple2.first(where: { (scoreInTuple2, index2InTuple2) in index2InTuple2 == indexInTuple1 }){
        return (scoreInTuple1, tupleIn2.0)
    }
    return nil
})
```

`(String, String)` should be change to the real type/class of `score` & `date1`.
Also, `index2InTuple2 == indexInTuple1` might be changed also if it's custom type/class which might not be `Equatable`.

With sample code before:

```
let tuple1 = [("score1", "index1"), ("score2", "index2"), ("score3", "index3")]
let tuple2 = [("date1", "index1"), ("date2", "index2"), ("date3", "index4")]
```

Debug log after:

```
print("tuple3: \(tuple3)")
```

Output:

```
$> tuple3: [("score1", "date1"), ("score2", "date2")]
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
let tuple1 = [("score1", "index1"), ("score2", "index2"), ("score3", "index3")]
let tuple2 = [("date1", "index1"), ("date2", "index2"), ("date3", "index4")]

let filtered = tuple1.filter {tuple2.map{$0.1}.contains($0.1)}
let result = filtered.map {tuple in
    return (tuple.0, tuple2.first(where: {$0.1 == tuple.1})!.0)
}

print (result)  // [("score1", "date1"), ("score2", "date2")]
```

I'm using Strings for simplicity, just make sure you are using *Equatable* objects in your tuples.